# Unaligned camera: red and yellow squares

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera, screencast

I'm having the following problem: camera has a trembling yellow square that moves when I move the camera view. Hoy could I align this squares ?

[image]

Comment: what is this yellow square?

Comment: What happens if you delete that camera and replace it with a new one?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is a bug or just something that I don't understand deeply. The thing is that changing the `clip start` value within the camera lenses solves the issue.

[image]